# torch.compile() can't retain/ backward grad?

Tags: python, pytorch

I can't backward grad on a non leaf tensor in a compiled function. The tensor still have no grad even though `retain_grad` is called

Example code to recreate the problem:

```py
import torch

@torch.compile
def f(v):
    v2 = v+1
    v2.retain_grad()
    v2.sum().backward()
    return v2.grad

v=torch.rand(4, requires_grad = True)
out=f(v)
print(out)
```

without the `@torch.compile` decorator, the output is `tensor([1., 1., 1., 1.])` as desired
but with the `@torch.compile` decorator, the output is `None` along with the warning:

```
UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the .grad field to be populated for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations. (Triggered internally at aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:486.)
  example_value = grapharg.example.grad
```

Does it have something to do with graph breaks in torch dynamo?
Am I missing something?
using pytorch 2.0.0+cu118 on google colab.